# @font-face not working (result font different from the original font)

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using the @font-face syntax in my tumblr theme. The fonts I installed were Doctor Soos Bold and Doctor Soos Light using the code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'doctor_soos_boldbold';
src: url('doctor_soos_bold_2.1-webfont.eot');
src: url('doctor_soos_bold_2.1-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('doctor_soos_bold_2.1-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('doctor_soos_bold_2.1-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('doctor_soos_bold_2.1-webfont.svg#doctor_soos_boldbold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}

@font-face {
font-family: 'doctor_soos_lightregular';
src: url('doctor_soos_light_1.1-webfont.eot');
src: url('doctor_soos_light_1.1-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('doctor_soos_light_1.1-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('doctor_soos_light_1.1-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('doctor_soos_light_1.1-webfont.svg#doctor_soos_lightregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}
```

The problem is whenever I use these fonts, the resulting font is different from the original font. The difference can be seen here http://celestetwit.tumblr.com/private/61000332979/tumblr_mszx4vL7iw1sdolt8

The code of course is placed within the style element. But because I don't know much about CSS and I also don't know if the premade custom tumblr theme I'm using is affecting the code above, I don't know which part went wrong. Please please help me in fixing this problem. The tumblr theme code I'm using can be found here http://pastebin.com/UqNL7X89 Please take a look at it for reference.

I also uploaded the fonts in tumblr and used the code below but I still get the same result.

```
@font-face {font-family: "doctorsoosbold"; src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/qvrmxer/a06msz0xg/doctor_soos_bold_2.1.ttf');}

@font-face {font-family: "doctorsooslight"; src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/qvrmxer/TpImsz0yf/doctor_soos_light_1.1.ttf');}
```

Also, when using these font-family in the code below, the result is also the same.

```
.entry h1{font-family: doctorsoosbold; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 20px; letter-spacing: 1px;}
```

Comment: my guess is that the fonts arent in that folder.

Comment: I don't see dr soos soos used anywhere :p

Comment: “The difference can be seen here” is far too vague; you should tell where the difference is and where the original font is available. Besides, `@font-face` just declares font, it does not actually apply them to anything, so you should also show the CSS rules that use the font families and the HTML markup to which those rules are supposed to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with what you have there.

1. You have declared the fonts "doctor_soos_boldbold" and "doctor_soos_lightregular" but you have not specified the correct path, at least, I believe you do not have those fonts in the current directory. You need to specify where the fonts are properly.

Where you have:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'doctor_soos_boldbold';
    src: url('doctor_soos_bold_2.1-webfont.eot');
    src: url('doctor_soos_bold_2.1-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('doctor_soos_bold_2.1-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('doctor_soos_bold_2.1-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('doctor_soos_bold_2.1-webfont.svg#doctor_soos_boldbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Every spot that starts with "url(" needs to have the correct URL to those fonts. Every single one. So, you need to make it:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'doctor_soos_boldbold';
    src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/qvrmxer/a06msz0xg/doctor_soos_bold_2.1.eot');
    src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/qvrmxer/a06msz0xg/doctor_soos_bold_2.1.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://static.tumblr.com/qvrmxer/a06msz0xg/doctor_soos_bold_2.1.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://static.tumblr.com/qvrmxer/a06msz0xg/doctor_soos_bold_2.1.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://static.tumblr.com/qvrmxer/a06msz0xg/doctor_soos_bold_2.1.svg#doctor_soos_boldbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You need to have the .eot file, the .woff, the .ttf, and .svg, all there, with those filenames. Do the same thing with the light fonts, all 4 files also.

Be aware that Firefox requires fonts to be on the same server as the requesting CSS, and I don't know if that applies to same subdomain also: meaning it may not work in Firefox if it needs to be on http://celestetwit.tumblr.com

1. You are also not applying those fonts to any elements on the page.

In order to do this, you need to pick an element, for example I'm going to pick ...

```
.entry { font-family: calibri; }
```

.. and by changing the font-family to:

```
.entry { font-family: 'doctor_soos_lightregular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

.. you will be able to see the updated font (it's a good idea to have fallbacks as I have shown above. Fixes an error in Windows XP/IE 8 to do with selects, for one thing.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. The font can now be seen but only in IE. And just like you said, it doesn't work on firefox and chrome even though the fonts were uploaded in tumblr.

Comment: No problem :) If you're happy with this answer, could you mark it as answered? Thanks!

Comment: you should also change font-weight to reflect your font-families...light-regular is 200, and bold is 600